# How to select rows of tensor based on condition (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Only using tensorflow, how can I select rows of a tensor that satisfy a condition?

Example tensor x:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 4]], dtype=int32)>
```

I'd like to create a new Tensor that only includes those rows of x where the first row element equals 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 4]])
x = tf.constant([i for i in x.numpy() if i[0] == 0)
```

Or only with tensorflow:

```
a = tf.constant([[0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 4]])
mask = tf.where(a[:,0] == 0, True, False)
a = tf.boolean_mask(a, mask)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use numpy in this specific problem. My code is part of a that will be converted to a computational graph by tensorflow, so I can only use tensorflow functions

Comment: You can't use numpy directly or at all? Tensorflow by default relies on numpy.

Comment: Apparently I can't use it, it throws this error: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: Are you able to use `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` before any `tf` calls (to then use `.numpy()`?

Comment: I need to run it in graph-execution mode

Comment: I found a solution without using numpy and added it to yours, Dijnn. Once it is approved I will accept your answer

Comment: Ah yes, that works! If you want, you could just make your own answer and accept it so you get the credit. I'm not sure if you'll get it by editing mine, but I've approved your edit. :)